# Get row from first table in many to many by two id from second table

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a problem with sql request. I have 3 tables.
table_1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | bbb |
| 3 | ccc |
| 4 | ddd |

table_2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | zzz |
| 2 | yyy |
| 3 | xxx |
| 4 | www |

And third table for many to many relationship.

table_1_table_2

| table_1_id | table_2_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |

And finally my question.
For example i have id from table_2 (1 and 2);
I need get all rows from table 1 which have row in t1_t2 where t2.id = 1 and 2
How to get this result:

| table_1_id | table_1_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 3 | ccc |

The code bottom is not working

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1`
JOIN `table_1_table_2` ON table_1.id=table_1_table_2.table_1_id
JOIN `table_2` ON table_2.id=table_1_table_2.table_2
WHERE table_2.id = 1 AND table_2.id = 2
```

Comment: You don't explain the logic tho. You have id(1,2) from table_2. What are the passages you need to get to your output?

Comment: I think you made some confusion in your output: zzz and xxx are not table_1 names

Comment: @etsa Oh, I didn't see that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join all tables. It's sufficient to use the relationships table to count amount of id2 for each id1, then join with tab1 if you want to gather id1 names.

```
SELECT tab1.id,
       tab1.name
FROM       tab1 
INNER JOIN tab12
        ON tab1.id = tab12.table_1_id
WHERE tab12.table_2_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY tab1.id,
         tab1.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tab12.table_2_id) = 2
```

**Output**:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 3 | ccc |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dg4jb4goBzpm6otzACJXUF/3).

Comment: But i need get rows from table_1, which have id from table_2, row in table_1 can have more 2 ids table_2

Comment: Update your post with the expected output.

Comment: Updated, will this help understand my question?

Comment: Almost but not quite, this return all rows table_1 which table_2id 1 OR 2 but i need 1 AND 2

Comment: I think I can't convey my whole idea, can I show you in any messenger that I'm trying to convey?

Comment: You can ensure both ids are found by imposing the condition `COUNT(DISTINCT table_2_id) = 2`. Check the just updated answer.

Comment: seems to work as it should, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2_table1 tt ON tt.table1_id = t1.id
JOIN table2 t2 ON tt.table2_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 'second_table_id1'
  AND t2.id = 'second_table_id2';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE table_2.id = 1 AND table_2.id = 2
```

it is impossible to have a row with two different ids in the same column
perhaps you meant:

```
WHERE table_1.id = 1 AND table_2.id = 2
```

Comment: But how i can get row from table_1, which have id from table_2?

Answer (score 0):

Others already answered, I just propose a slight different way:
Example data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id      INT,        
    name    VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1,     'aaa'),
(2,     'bbb'),
(3,     'ccc'),
(4,     'ddd');

CREATE TABLE t2(
    id      INT,
    name    VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
(1,     'zzz'),
(2,     'yyy'),
(3,     'xxx'),
(4,     'www');

CREATE TABLE t1_2(
    t1_id       INT,
    t2_id       INT
);
INSERT INTO t1_2 VALUES
(1,     1),
(1,     2),
(3,     3),
(4,     4);
```

Query:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT t1_id, COUNT(*) AS RC
            FROM t1_2
            GROUP BY t1_id) Tab1_2 ON t1.id=Tab1_2.t1_id
WHERE Tab1_2.RC=2
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaa  |
+----+------+
```

> ---- after your question update

example data

```
...
CREATE TABLE t1_2(
    t1_id       INT,
    t2_id       INT
);
INSERT INTO t1_2 VALUES
(1,     1),
(1,     2),
(3 ,1),
(3,2),
(3,     3),
(4,     4);
```

Query

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT t1_id 
            FROM t1_2  
            WHERE t1_2.t2_id IN (1,2)
            ) t12 ON t1.id=t12.t1_id
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaa  |
|  3 | ccc  |
+----+------+
```